# How can I belongTo (Store) depand on belongTo(Company)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to link these two BelongTo together so that when he chooses from (Company) he displays the (Store) related to his (company_id)

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * Get the store
     *
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
    }
     /**
     * Get the company
     *
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
}
```

and this is my resource User

```
      public function fields(Request $request){

    return[
    BelongsTo::make(__('Company'), 'company', Company::class),
    BelongsTo::make(__('Store'), 'store', Store::class)];
    }
}
```